# how to install phpmailer with phpspreadsheet installed local server

Tags: php, phpmailer, phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

i have installed PHP-spreadsheet library to save data in MySQL database to excel file. now i wanted to send emails from my site using PHP-mailer. when i try to install PHP-mailer package using composer following error massage[image]

then i try to download package and copy it to folder but it also not work.

how can i install and work with both libraries.

Comment: You need to enable GD extention

Answer (score 0):

This error has nothing to do with PHPMailer. The error says that phpspreadsheet requires the `gd` PHP extension, which you don't have, so all you should need to do is install or enable it.